# Chisq.test with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a table (already a crosstab), which contains several variables with their categories. I want to run chi-squared tests for each indicator (without looping over the table, if possible). An important thing is that each indicator should be tested separately from other indicators.

Here is my dataset

```
    table2 <-  data.frame(
  indicator = c("A_3_respondent_hohh", "A_3_respondent_hohh", 
                   "B_2_hh_hosting_displaced_persons", "B_2_hh_hosting_displaced_persons", 
                   "o7_current_settlement_type", "o7_current_settlement_type", "o7_current_settlement_type"
), 
var = c("no", "yes", "no", "yes", "city_smt", "regional_center", 
           "village"), 
n_female = c(3L,  3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
n_male = c(NA, 9L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, NA), 
n_Overall = c(3L, 12L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L)
)
```

I use the following approach to handle it

```
tbl2 <- table2 |>
  select(indicator, var, starts_with("n_"), -c(n_Overall)) |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("n_"), ~replace_na(.x, 0))) |>
  group_by(indicator) |>
  mutate(var  = as.factor(var)) |>
  summarise(chi_st = chisq.test(n_male, n_female)$statistic,
            chi_p = chisq.test(n_male, n_female)$p.value)
```

It throws an error on "A_3_respondent_hohh" indicator

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `chi_st = chisq.test(n_male, n_female)$statistic`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: indicator = "A_3_respondent_hohh".
Caused by error in `chisq.test()`:
! 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

But it works when I run the test on this indicator solely

```
t2 <- table2 |> filter(indicator == "A_3_respondent_hohh") |>
  select(indicator, var, starts_with("n_"), -c(n_Overall)) |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("n_"), ~replace_na(.x, 0)))
chisq.test(t[, c("n_male", "n_female")])
```

Thus, the question is how the issue with grouped indicators could be resolved.

Also, strangely, when I run the test on the rest of the indicators within summarize() and individually, the test statistic slightly varies. Why could it happen?

P.S. I know, that Fisher's exact test would be a better solution in this case, but I need a Chi-squared test to be here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you pass a `data.frame` with just two columns `n_male` and `n_female` to `cisq.test()`. We can do the same within the `group_by()`. The difference is that in the `group_by()` in your first example you use both arguments `x` and `y`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

table2 |>
  select(indicator, var, starts_with("n_"), -c(n_Overall)) |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("n_"), ~replace_na(.x, 0))) |>
  group_by(indicator) |>
  mutate(var  = as.factor(var)) |>
  # we first save the result wrapped in `list()`:
  summarise(chi_sq = list(chisq.test(across(starts_with("n_"))))) |>
  # now we can use `rowwise()` and add elements of the test to the data.frame in `mutate()` call:
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(chi_st = chi_sq$statistic,
         chi_p  = chi_sq$p.value)

#> Warning in chisq.test(across(starts_with("n_"))): Chi-squared approximation may
#> be incorrect

#> Warning in chisq.test(across(starts_with("n_"))): Chi-squared approximation may
#> be incorrect

#> Warning in chisq.test(across(starts_with("n_"))): Chi-squared approximation may
#> be incorrect
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   indicator                        chi_sq  chi_st  chi_p
#>   <chr>                            <list>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A_3_respondent_hohh              <htest> 2.93   0.0867
#> 2 B_2_hh_hosting_displaced_persons <htest> 0.0142 0.905 
#> 3 o7_current_settlement_type       <htest> 5.18   0.0751
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>